# Explaining the red elements with BS that appear when training my Keras model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network, monte-carlo-tree-search

I am pretty new to keras, but have done the Mnist-dataset and achieved 99.2% accuracy, so i at least know how to train a model. The problem i have with this is that it looks quite different from the other training samples i have done. I pulled a git repo and worked from there. can anyone explain this output:

This is the output i was expecting: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8YFB.png)

But i keep getting something like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51zmr.png)

Comment: Hi @Simen Qvam, Which system OS, TensorFlow and python version are you using? Please share [minimal reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code to replicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

It would've been helpful had you shared the git repo you used.

While this is unusual when a keras model gets trained, it is due to the other dependencies which the imported packages may be using which is causing this sort of a formatting inside the training message.

Different packages have their way of displaying the training progress.

If this doesn't affect your model performance, there is no need to get stuck on that.